# Logging in using voice commands with GDM

Tags: login, software-rec, gdm, speech-recognition

Is there a program capable of doing such thing?

Something that would wait for me to either supply a username and a password, or select my username and a voice command that does the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

From Wikipedia:

> There is currently no open-source
> equivalent of proprietary speech
> recognition software (e.g. Nuance's
> Dragon NaturallySpeaking or Windows
> Speech Recognition) for GNU/Linux.
> However, there are several incomplete,
> open-source projects and solutions
> that could be used to attain some
> elements of speech recognition in the
> free operating system. It is also
> possible to use Windows speech
> recognition software under GNU/Linux.

Also from Wikipedia:

> Solutions
>
> The following is a list of current
> projects dedicated to implementing
> speech recognition in Linux, as well
> as major (though mostly incomplete)
> native solutions that are available as
> of March 2008:
>
> *CVoiceControl is a KDE and X Window independent version of its predecessor KVoiceControl
>
> *DynaSpeak from SRI International (speaker-independent speech recognition software
> development kit that scales from small- to large-scale systems, for use in commercial,
> consumer, and military applications)
>
> *CMU Sphinx is a general term to describe a group of speech recognition systems
> developed at Carnegie Mellon University.
>
> *GnomeVoiceControl is a dialogue system to control the GNOME Desktop that was developed
> in the Google Summer of Code in 2007.
>
> *Julius is a high-performance, two-pass large vocabulary continuous speech recognition
> (LVCSR) decoder software for speech-related researchers and developers.
>
> *LumenVox Speech Engine is a commercial library for Linux and Windows for inclusion in
> other software. It has been integrated into the Asterisk private branch exchange
> system [2]
>
> *Open Mind Speech a part of the Open Mind Initiative and aims to develop free (GPL)
> speech recognition tools and applications, as well as collect speech data.
>
> *PerlBox is a perl based control and speech output.
>
> *Simon (This project aims at being extremely flexible to compensate dialects or even
> speech impairments; requires HTK and Julius)
>
> *VoxForge is a free speech corpus and acoustic model repository for open source speech
> recognition engines.
>
> *Xvoice (requires ViaVoice to function)
>
> *Verbio ASR is a commercial speech recognition server for Linux and windows platforms.
>
> *Platypus is a open source shim that will allow Dragon NaturallySpeaking running under
> wine to work with any linux x11 application.
>
> *Vedics is a speech assistant for GNOME Environment

Probably to use any of these tools you should write some kind of script yourself.
Good luck!

Comment: Hopefully this tools have improved since march 2008